# Create OG group on registration

Tags: 7, rules, organic-groups, users

I have different registration pages for different user roles in drupal, for some users i would like them to be able to create an OG group when there accounts is created.

I have a field in the registration form for group name which i would like to be used in creating the new group.

Im sure this is something you can do with rules but i cant seem to find any good tutorials on seeting it up any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use this module http://drupal.org/project/uc_node_checkout

You can assign a node/content type to a product in uber cart, so once a visitor has selected a product in the cart they can create an og group node.

for my needs I then just used rules to make the group unpublished until the visitor had a fully paid for the role in the ubercrt

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7, after user registration form submit you can create the group.

- It can be done using this [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) which is used for 
  **form-specific alteration** instead of the **global hook_form_alter**().
- It can also be done using **[hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)** and **rules**

For this example I'm using **hook_form_FORM_ID_alter**

- After the configuration of **[Organic groups](https://drupal.org/project/og)** and **creating group content type**(machine name is **groups**) using **admin/structure/types/add**

  [image]

`/**
 * Implement hook_form_user_register_form_alter().
 */
function test_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'create_group_on_user_registration';
}
/**
 * Custom submit function for user registration form
 */
function create_group_on_user_registration($form, &$form_state) {
  $usr_obj = $form_state['user']; //get registered user object
  if (is_object($usr_obj) && isset($usr_obj->uid) && (your_conditions)) {// dont forget to add your conditions
    $bodytext = "group body";
    $author_id = 1;//you can change author id, i'm making admin as author
    $node = new stdClass(); // Create a new node object
    $node->type = "groups"; // Group content type
    node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values
    $node->title = "group title2";
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled
    //for author id I have given admin, you can give any other user id, 
    //but  that user should have permission to create group cotent type
    $node->uid = $author_id; // UID of the author of the node; or use $node->name
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = $bodytext;
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($bodytext);
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html';
    if ($node = node_submit($node)) { // Prepare node for saving
      node_save($node);//$node->nid will have node id
    }
  }
}`

NOTE :

- Go through all comments
- Make changes as per your requirements